# How to add tab listener to the tabs

Tags: android, tabs, camera, fragment

So I wanted to add camera intent in my app..But in my app when you click the "Open Camera" button  it opens camera but i want the camera to come up as soon as I click the Photo Tab.. Please someone help me I would be very Thankful.

TABS

```
/**
     * return the current tab number
     * 0 = Gallery_Fragment
     * 1 = Photo_Fragment
     * @return
     */
    public int getCurrentTabNumber(){
        return mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    }

/**
 * setup viewpager for manager the tabs
 */
private void setupViewPager(){
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter =  new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new GalleryFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new PhotoFragment());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsBottom);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);




    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(getString(R.string.gallery));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(getString(R.string.photo));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```

PHOTOFRAGMENT

public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "PhotoFragment";

```
//constant
private static final int PHOTO_FRAGMENT_NUM =1;
private static final int GALLERY_FRAGMENT_NUM =2;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 5;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started.");

    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLaunchCamera);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Launching Camera");

            if (((ShareActivity)getActivity()).getCurrentTabNumber()== PHOTO_FRAGMENT_NUM){
                if (((ShareActivity)getActivity()).checkPermissions(Permissions.CAMERA_PERMISSIONS[0])){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting camera");
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), ShareActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: done taking a photo.");
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: attempting to navigate tofinal share screen");
        //navigate to the final share screen to publish photo

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == YOUR_CAMERA_TAB_POSITION) {
               // do camera logic here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: @Harris glad it did ! happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

for increase speed of camera coming up , you can use below code in your manifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

and for tab listener you can try this

```
 topTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            if (tab.getPosition ==  2/*your camera tab position*/ )

            //do somthing

             }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate you my friend, please vote for me if it was helpful